# Crystal reports, get sum for specific reocrds

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

**In Short:** 
I need to get a total for customer groups + the credits - the debits in a specific date range.

**In Detail:**

I'm creating an invoice report for customer orders. Each Customer belongs to a group, and I need to group the invoice by customer group so I can give a total amount owed for the customer group.

So the top Group in the report is customers.group_name with the total for the group in the group header.

The second group is orders.customer_id with the total for the customer in the group header.

I have 2 parameter for the date range of orders which I use in the select expert

I have another table for credits and debits for each group.

This are the fields for the CreditDebits Table

- group_name
- date_
- type_ (this can be either "credit" or "debit")
- amount

I've linked customers.group_name with CreditsDebits.group_name in the database expert.

I also use the date range parameters for this table

Do get the credits I created a formula called "credists" like so

```
if {Credits_Debits.type} = "credit" then sum({Credits_Debits.amount})
```

But when I drop this formula on the customers.group_name header, the formula shows up as empty and the total for the group gets messed up (it becomes triple of what it should be.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First check `Does this field CreditsDebits.group_name consists of customer name? or any different name?`

Place the formula `if {Credits_Debits.type} = "credit" then sum({Credits_Debits.amount})` in footer but not in header and check.

Comment: This didn't help, it seems to to add the credits for each order to the total.

Comment: you need to place in date group group footer